# Progress OpenEdge, ODBC, recordsets, joining, oh my

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, progress-4gl, openedge

So frustrated here. I'm not a DB Admin but can get around. I'm writing some ODBC queries against a Progress OpenEdge database that we only have view access to. For the longest time there have been no problems until recently they changed the data structure and for who knows why, they moved customer phone numbers into their own table called "contact" whereas before they were in "cif", where the address etc still remain.

Instead of creating the "contact" table with one row for for each customer and fields for each phone number, they use a code of 0-4, number/email, and customer. So if a customer has 4 phone numbers, they have 4 rows with different code, contact fields and customer name repeated.

I'm trying to join the "contact" table with the "cif" table so it returns each mention of customer in "cif" no matter how many times it is listed in "cif", but include all phone numbers associated from "contact" in each line.

Table structure simplified is like so:

```
Table "contact"

code |   contact(#)  | customer
--------------------------------
  0  | (123)456-7890 | ABC Corp
  1  | (123)456-7891 | ABC Corp
  0  | (987)654-3210 | CBA Inc


Table "cif"

customer | b_in_low | b_in_high
----------------------------------
ABC Corp |  50.45   | 134.66
ABC Corp |  64.45   | 188.99
CBA Inc  |  12.56   | 890.33
```

What I'm trying to return is a joined row for each row in "cif" but include all numbers from "contact" so the table above would return:

rsRow1) ABC Corp, 0, (123)456-7890, 1, (123)456-7891, 50.45, 134.66

rsRow2) ABC Corp, 0, (123)456-7890, 1, (123)456-7891, 64.45, 188.99

rsRow3) CBA Inc, 0, (987)654-3210,,, 12.56, 890.00

What I do NOT want:

rsRow1) ABC Corp, 0, #, 50.45, 134.66

rsRow2) ABC Corp, 1, #, 50.45, 134.66

rsRow3) ABC Corp, 0, #, 64.45, 188.99

rsRow4) ABC Corp, 1, #, 64.45, 188.99

rsRow5) CBA Inc, 0, #, 12.56 | 890.00

Make sense? I can get it to work by one rs on the "cif" table and during each repeat region, perform another query on "contact" using the "cif.customer" as a WHERE filter but obviously it is extremely slow and would result in potentially thousands of queries.

I can get it to return only 1 line from "cif" but only 1 number from "contact"

or

I can get it to return up to 5 duplicate "cif" lines with the 5 different phone numbers for each.

So in a nutshell, how can I efficiently get 1 row from "cif" while listing all +-5 phone numbers from "contact"?

Comment: I can't see a way to do this without writing some code on the result side to turn rows in to columns.

Comment: that's why I cam here Tim :D I ended up using ajax to pull in a formatted page for the contact info on it's own. At least for now anyway. Working well for our needs and infinitely faster than putting a second recordset within the first, even though it's essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Is the intended result correct? Shouldn't the 2 on the line with ABC Corp be a 1?
So:
ABC Corp, 0, (123)456-7890,1,(123)456-7891,50.45,134.66

Comment: You are correct Ronald...typo...both rows with 2 should be 1. Updated OP

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT c.customer
     , ISNULL(c1.code,'')
     , ISNULL(c1.contact,'')
     , ISNULL(c2.code,'')
     , ISNULL(c2.contact,'')
     , ISNULL(c3.code,'')
     , ISNULL(c3.contact,'')
     , ISNULL(c4.code,'')
     , ISNULL(c4.contact,'')
     , ISNULL(c5.code,'')
     , ISNULL(c5.contact,'')
     , c.b_in_low
     , c.b_in_high
FROM CIF AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact AS c1
ON c1.customer = c.customer
AND c1.code = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact AS c2
ON c2.customer = c.customer
AND c2.code = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact AS c3
ON c3.customer = c.customer
AND c3.code = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact AS c4
ON c4.customer = c.customer
AND c4.code = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact AS c5
ON c5.customer = c.customer
AND c5.code = 1
```

It depends on the type of the field 'code' what is returned, if you want it to be blank you probably have to do another translation.

Not pretty, but I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is an XML option in SQL server that lets you take multiple results and merge them into a concatenated string in a single field. It's the STUFF FOR XML PATH command. Here's an example of how I've I used it.

```
SELECT call_number,  item_number,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',','''' 
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), item_line) + '**‘ 
        + item_number + '**‘ + work_code + ''''
        FROM stage_call_item_detail s
        WHERE h.source_system_code = s.source_system_code
        AND h.domain_code = s.domain_code
        AND h.call_number = s.call_number
        AND s.site_code IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 2
        FOR XML PATH(''))
    ,1, 1, '‘)  ,'<item_number>',''''),'</item_number>','''') call_line_item_list, *
FROM stage_ssm_call_history h
WHERE call_number = 'A1014-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use buffers when building a query?

If you can, you could do something like:

define buffers contactA ... contactN for contact.

```
FOR EACH cif WHERE cif.customer = "ABC Corp",
FIRST contact OF cif OUTER-JOIN,
FIRST contactA OF cif WHERE ROWID(contactA) <> ROWID(contact) OUTER-JOIN,
...
FIRST contactN of cif
WHERE ROWID(contactN) <> ROWID(contact) 
AND ROWID(contactN) <> ROWID(contactA)
...
```

This is not a nice solution, and performance can be affected seriously... And this will only work if you have limited number of contacts, say, 0-4.

Comment: Thanks yursol. What I ended up doing and is working well for our needs is to do a single simple query and use ajax to call the second query for each customer. It's not ideal but it works and only delays the result by a few seconds. For our needs on this report which isn't run but a couple times a day, it will suffice. Not an ideal solution but until I can figure out a better, more efficient one, this will do the trick.